# Adding an onclick event handler to videos doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, video, onclick, event-handling, dom-events

For some reason, when I try to add an `onclick` event handler to all videos on my page, it doesn't work.

```
(function(){
    var videos = document.getElementsByTagName("video");
    console.log(videos);
    console.log(videos.length);
    for(var i=0;i<videos.length;i++){
        videos[i].onclick = function(){
            console.log("aaa");
        }
    }
})();
```

When I first `console.log()` the variable `videos`, the console outputs a `NodeList` with two elements. But when I `console.log()` `videos.length` the console outputs `0`. Thus, adding the `onclick` to the videos doesn't work. May it be due to the fact that videos aren't manually added to the page? Here is the complete JS code:

```
(function(){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET","video_list.json",true);
    request.onload = function(){
        if(request.status == 200){
            updateVideoListDOM(request.responseText);
        }
    }
    request.send();
})();

(function(){
    var videos = document.getElementsByTagName("video");
    console.log(videos);
    console.log(videos.length);
    for(var i=0;i<videos.length;i++){
        videos[i].onclick = function(){
            console.log("aaa");
        }
    }
})();

function updateVideoListDOM(videoListObject){
    //video_list mora da bude u .json formatu, jer anonymous funkcija iznad ne vrsi konverziju
    var videoListArray = JSON.parse(videoListObject).videoListArray;
    for(var i = 0;i<videoListArray.length;i++){ 
        if(checkVideoExist(videoListArray[i])){
            var element = document.createElement("video");
            element.setAttribute("src",videoListArray[i]);
        }
        else{
            var element = document.createElement("p");
            element.innerHTML = "Sorry, the specified video doesn't exist.";
        }
        document.getElementById("videos").appendChild(element);
    }
}

function checkVideoExist(url){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET",url,true);
    request.send();
    return !(request.status == 404);
}
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XMLHttpRequest being asynchronous, the updateVideoListDOM function gets called after you try to set onclick.

You should name your function like this :

```
function updateVideoOnClick() {
    var videos = document.getElementsByTagName("video");
    for(var i=0;i<videos.length;i++){
        videos[i].onclick = function(){
            console.log("aaa");
        }
    }
}
```

And call this function after creating the videos :

```
   ...
     document.getElementById("videos").appendChild(element);
    }
    updateVideoOnClick();
}
```

You could also simplify all this by setting the onclick event while creating the videos :

```
...
var element = document.createElement("video");
element.setAttribute("src",videoListArray[i]);
element.onclick = function(){
    console.log("aaa");
}
...
```

So that you don't loop twice over your videos.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't really understand the asynchronous thing at first.

Comment: You're welcome.

The XMLHttpRequest to video_list.json can take anything from a few miliseconds to many seconds to load depending on your network.

And even on local it will always be longer that calling your anonymous function, so it will (almost) always be called later.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you try to add the onClick event handler to the video element before you create the video element, you can just add the event handler in the updateVideoListDOM function like this :

```
function updateVideoListDOM(videoListObject){
    //video_list mora da bude u .json formatu, jer anonymous funkcija iznad ne vrsi konverziju
    var videoListArray = JSON.parse(videoListObject).videoListArray;
    for(var i = 0;i<videoListArray.length;i++){ 
        if(checkVideoExist(videoListArray[i])){
            var element = document.createElement("video");
            element.setAttribute("src",videoListArray[i]);
        }
        else{
            var element = document.createElement("p");
            element.innerHTML = "Sorry, the specified video doesn't exist.";
        }
        element.onclick = function(){
            console.log("aaa");
        }
        document.getElementById("videos").appendChild(element);
    }
}
```

Comment: in the line request.open("GET","video_list.json",true) you pass true to the request.open function which makes the request-response asynchronous if you want synchronous  request-response pass false instead of true